# simple_form set default value for integer collection fails, why?

Tags: collections, default, simple-form

Try to set a selected value for a integer collection in simple_form always fails! why this is highly frustrating and don't understand why.

printing @profile.age in view it is correctly value 19

View:

```
  = f.input :age_from,
            :collection => 18..60,
            :selected => @profile.age
```

Results:

```
 defaults to 18
```

View:

```
  = f.input :age_from,
            :collection => 18..60,
            :selected => "#{@profile.age}"
```

Results:

```
 to defaults to 18
```

adding :selected => "#{@profile.age.to_s}

Results:

```
defaults to 18
```